# bootstrap panel margin not 0 when it should be

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a simple bootstrap panel.  I'm setting margins to 0, but it looks like it isn't 0.  See attached.  The margin says "-", which I presume means 0.  But when highlighted, I see the big block of orange.  Is this telling me the margin extends all the way to the right of the screen?  I want to put another panel to the right (side-by-side), and it's pushing it to underneath this panel.

[image]

Comment: Post the link for that JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonJSFiddle/zKX6G/

Comment: Things would be different if you would put another block besides it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. It's a block element. That's how block elements behave.

If you want something next to that div either change the div to `display: inline-block;` or `float` it `left` or `right` (e.g., `float: left;`). Choose whichever fits your needs.